# Spring Roo "Undo create"/"Undo manage" root cause?

Tags: spring-roo

Is there a way to find out *why* Roo creates something (in this case a controller but that's not always the case) and then later issues `"Undo create..."` & `"Undo manage..."` messages? This is *very* frustrating.

I've yet to find a way to get Roo to dump more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to see more information about Roo shell errors when you execute an operation you could use the following command and then execute your operation again:

`roo> development mode`

This command will activate development mode and it will show you possible exceptions.

Hope this help.

Comment: No extra information is dumped to the Roo console, does it go elsewhere? Is there a way to modify Roo's logging settings directly?

Comment: Are you executing Spring Roo shell on STS or in system shell? If you are using system shell `development mode` command should work correctly... I'm not sure if it works on STS Spring Roo shell... Anyway, you could modify Spring Roo log level updating property `felix.log.level` from file `spring-roo-folder/conf/config.properties`. More info about Felix log level http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-configuration-properties.html

Comment: Neither way (STS nor system shell) seems to have any effect. I'll try the felix.log.level.  Thanks.